# tkinter - set geometry without showing window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to line up some label and canvas widgets.  To do so I need to know how wide my label boxes are.  I'd like my widget to auto-adjust if the user changes the system font size, so I don't want to hard code 12 pixels per character.  If I measure the label widget it's always 1 pixel wide.  Until I call .update(), then I get the correct value.  But .update() puts a window onscreen with my label, said window then goes away when I finally pack my final widgets.  But this causes an unwelcome flash when I first put up the widget.

So, how can I measure a label widget without .update()'ing it?  Or how can I .update() a widget without having it display onscreen?  I'm using Python if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Withdraw the window before calling update. The command you want is wm_withdraw

```
root = Tk()
root.wm_withdraw()
<your code here>
root.wm_deiconify()
```

However, if your real problem is lining up widgets you usually don't need to know the size of widgets. Use the grid geometry manager. Get out a piece of graph paper and lay  your widgets out on it. Feel free to span as many squares as necessary for each widget. The design can then translate easily to a series of grid calls.